# Parse deeply nested JSON as Scala Option[Object]

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

I have read several JSON parsing techniques, but I cannot exactly understand how to get the functionality I want. I am trying to parse a deeply nested JSON, returned from the Facebook Graph API (user messages). The JSON I am trying to parse is of the form:

```
{
"data":[
  {
     "id":"",
     "to":{
        "data":[
           {
              "id":"",
              "name":""
           },
           {
              "id":"",
              "name":""
           }
        ]
     },
     "updated_time":"2014-07-04T22:43:41+0000",
     "unread":0,
     "unseen":0,
     "comments":{
        "data":[
           {
              "id":"",
              "from":{
                 "id":"",
                 "name":""
              },
              "message":"",
              "created_time":""
           },
           {
              "id":"",
              "from":{
                 "id":"",
                 "name":""
              },
              "message":"",
              "created_time":""
           }
        ],
        "paging":{
           "previous":""
        }
     }
  }
],
"paging":{
  "previous":"",
  "next":""
},
"summary":{
  "unseen_count":0,
  "unread_count":0,
  "updated_time":"2014-07-04T22:13:37+0000"
 }
}
```

As you can see, it is quite deeply nested. I have been trying to parse this with Play JSON (JSON Macro Inception). I have created case classes for each of the layers.

```
case class User(id: String)
case class To(data: Seq[User])
case class Message(message: Option[String], from: User, created_time: String)
case class Comment(data: Array[Message], paging: Paging)
case class Chat(id: String, to: To, updated_time: String, comments: Option[Comment])
case class Paging(previous: String, next: String)
case class Summary(updated_time: String)
case class FBInbox(data: Array[Chat], paging: Paging, summary: Summary)
```

This seems to work well. However, I want each layer to return an Option[] for each member of each class. This way, if anything is missing, there won't be a problem. My question is, if I parse the JSON as the head level using `Json.asOpt[FBInbox]`, will that propagate the 'Option' for each element down through each level? If not, is there a different JSON parser I can use that has this functionality (Argonaut, Lift, Jackson)?

In summary, I would like to be able to parse the entire JSON, and have an option for each member in each class. Then, I can retrieve data from the parsed JSON if it exists, and handle the case if it is None. Is this a correct approach so far? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply declare each of the members optional in the case classes?

Comment: No - I can do that. However, by doing this will it provide similar functionality as Json.asOpt() in returning an element if it exists and None if it does not? In other words, if I declare of the members as optional, will it parse them as such or will it just wrap the object in an Option?

Comment: No, I don't think it's the same think at all. One says the *whole* object may not exist and the other says it will necessarily exist *but* any of its attributes may not.